# How to save Doubly_Linked_Lists text to a file for Ada language? Also how to have not fixed size string input?

Tags: ada

I am writing a school project to store string to the doubly linked list, but I don't know how to save the final list to a text file. I also what the user to choose the text file name. Can someone show me how to do that? Also for Ada can I have a not fixed-length string as input? Right now I set the string length to 5 but I really wanted to have a flexible length for the string. Below is my code thank you.

```
with Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists;
with Ada.Text_Io; use Ada.Text_Io;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.IO_Exceptions;

procedure main is
   type Command is (A, C, P, E, M);
   package Command_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO (Command);
   package String_List is new Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists(Unbounded_String);
   use String_List;
   Userinput : String(1 .. 5) := (others => ' '); --This string length is 5
   InsertLocation : String(1 .. 5) := (others => ' '); --This string length is 5
   text : List; -- List is from Doubly_Linked_Lists
   F : File_Type;

begin   
   loop     
      declare
         Cmd : Command;


   procedure Print(Position : Cursor) is -- this subprogram print all string from list 
         begin     
            Put_Line(To_String(Element(Position)));      
            --Put_Line("K");
   end Print;

      begin
         Put_Line("*****************************");
         Put_Line("*Enter A to add a text      *");
         Put_Line("*Enter C to insert a text   *");
         Put_Line("*Enter P the print text list*");
         Put_Line("*Enter E the exit program   *");
         Put_Line("*Enter M to save the list   *");
         Put_Line("*****************************");
         Put_Line(" ");
         Put(">> ");

         Command_IO.Get (Cmd);

         Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line;

         Put_Line ("read " & Cmd'Image);                -- ' to sort out the not-fully-Ada-aware syntax highlighting
         Put_Line ("  " );
         case Cmd is

         when a =>
            Put_Line("Enter a text " );
            Put(">> " );
            Get(Userinput);  
            text.Append(To_Unbounded_String(Userinput)); -- if letter is a add it to the doubly link list  
            Put_line("  " );

         when c => 
            Put_Line("Enter a text location you want to insert " );
            Put(">> " );
            Get(Userinput);
            Put_Line("Enter a text " );
            Put(">> " );
            Get(InsertLocation);


            text.Insert(Before => text.Find(To_Unbounded_String(Userinput)), New_Item => To_Unbounded_String( InsertLocation ));

         when p =>      
            text.Iterate(Print'access);
            Put_line("  " );


         when m =>
            Put_Line("Save to file"); 
            Create (F, Out_File, "file.txt");
            Put_Line (F, "This string will be written to the file file.txt");
            Close (F);

         when e =>      
            Put_Line("Program Exit");

            exit;   

         end case;   

      exception
         when Ada.IO_Exceptions.Data_Error =>
            Put_Line ("unrecognised command");
            Put_Line (" ");

      end;
   end loop;
end main;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You look like you have all the parts.  You can use Text_IO for writing to the file and you can use Unbounded_String to hold strings of any size.  For reading in strings of any size, you can use the procedure [Get_Line](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-1.html#I6458) in Text_IO which returns a string of any length or if you really want to use Unbounded_Strings, you can use [Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO.Get_Line](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-12.html#I6551).  I could also optionally suggest looking at [Indefinite_Doubly_Linked_List](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-12.html#I7277) instead of using Unbounded_String, depending on your use case.

For writing to file, just loop over the List and write each element to a file using Text_IO style functions.

Here is some scaffolding showing some of this.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Doubly_Linked_Lists;
use Ada.Containers;


procedure Hello is

    package Lists is new Indefinite_Doubly_Linked_Lists(String);
    Text : Lists.List;
begin
    Put_Line("Hello, world!");


    Put_Line("Enter a text:" );
    declare
        User_Input : String := Get_Line;
    begin
        Text.Append(New_Item => User_Input);
    end;

    Put_Line("Enter Text to Insert at:");
    declare
        Location : String := Get_Line;
    begin
        Put_Line("Enter New Text:");
        declare
            User_Input : String := Get_Line;
        begin
            Text.Insert(Before => Text.Find(Location), New_Item => User_Input);
        end;
    end;

    -- Loop through list and write each element
    for Line of Text loop
        Put_Line(Line);
        -- Write to file here using Text_IO file operations
    end loop;

end Hello;
```

Side note, if you spend more time searching your data than you do creating your list, you can also look at Map packages.  Ada has both [hashed](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-5.html#I6908) and [ordered](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-14.html#I7279) maps (with indefinite options as well).

Comment: I don't believe you need Unbounded strings here : the Indefinite form of linked list combined with Simon's string initialisation should be enough.

Comment: The unbounded strings was just a hold over from when I was playing with it on an online Ada compiler.  I removed it.  I already had string initialization in my answer.  Is there something additional you think I should add to it?  Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of observations:

(1) Although a `String` is a fixed-length object, the length can be determined at initialisation:

```
declare
   Str : constant String := Get_Line;
begin
   ...
```

You may have to be a bit creative about using the value in `Str` outside its scope, the declare block. For example, if it’s the name of a file to be opened, the `File_Type` object to be opened could be in an outer scope.

(2) If you want to read an integer, use `Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get` (followed by `Skip_Line`, because the `Get` terminates when the number has been read, leaving the rest of the line, including the terminator, in the input buffer)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are on the right path.

A couple of points :

- you can ask the user to enter a filename (e.g. in a funciton returning String, used to initialise a variable as in Simon's answer. This function could suggest a default which will be used if the user just presses Return. Then you pass that string to the `Create` call.
- Probably the best way to output complex things like lists is to learn Stream I/O. This may be more complex to set up than you need right now, but ultimately it would let you simply "Write" the whole list to file in a single operation. Each data type has `'Read` and `'Write` attributes, which are procedures you can overload with your own procedures to format the file however you wish. The default `'Write` attribute for a list will iterate over the whole List calling each element's own `'Write` procedure. (It may also insert information about the List you don't want, that's why it's overloadable...)